# Angular-dart: "target of URI..."

Tags: eclipse, dart

I searched high and low for this issue and, while I found reports of the same error ubiquitously, I didn't find this specific error and can't seem to resolve it. I'm just now learning Dart and am following the Angular-Dart tutorial, and I keep getting this error early on, with no explanation that I can find. This is my badge_controller file:

```
library s1_basics.badge_controller;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';

@NgController(
selector: '[badge-controller]',
publishAs: 'ctrl'
)
class BadgeController {
  static const DEFAULT_NAME = 'Anne Bonney';
  static const LABEL1 = 'Arrr! Write yer name!';
  static const LABEL2 = 'Aye! Gimme a name!';
  String name = '';

  bool get inputIsNotEmpty => name.trim().isNotEmpty;
  String get label => inputIsNotEmpty ? LABEL1 : LABEL2;

  generateName() {
    name = DEFAULT_NAME;
  }
}
```

And this is my pirate_module file:

```
library s1_basics.pirate_module;

import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:s1_basics/badge_controller.dart';

class PirateModule extends Module {
  PirateModule() {
    type(BadgeController);
  }
}
```

I'm so early on in this tutorial that I don't think there's much else that I can show to debug this, but if anyone has an idea, I'd greatly appreciate it. Cheers!

Comment: What's the error message, where do you get it, (build, launch) which browser (Dartium, Chrome,...) which Angular version, Dart version,...? How does your `pubspec.yaml` file look like? Can you also please add the links to the pages where you found the error mentioned.

Comment: I just messed around with some of the paths and either the docs are wrong, or they're just wrong for this version. I just changed all the paths to relative paths and now it's working, so I think that might be the fix.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the import paths to be relative references for the imported files seems to fix it; i.e. initially this gave errors:

```
import 'package:s1_basics/pirate_module.dart';
```

but after changing it to

```
import '../lib/pirate_module.dart';
```

it worked...so that's the fix (for this) if anyone out there has issues.

Comment: Upon further inspection, my "lib" folder was nested under the main "s1_basics" folder rather than being under the "web" folder as it should have. I don't have the instructions in front of me, so this was either an oversight on my part, or the instructions were wrong (probably the former).

Comment: Looks like you are doing weir things. If your application is in `myapp` the the others should be `myapp/web` and `myapp/lib`. It's not obvous what `s1_basics` would be, maybe similar to `myapp` in my example.

Comment: I agree that I'm doing "weird" things...however, the tutorial I'm following says to do it this way. First it says to make sure that "lib" is at the same level as "web," which was how I did it initially...but when I launched Chromium, the error was based on not being able to find a file, and it said it was looking in "web/lib/...etc"...which suggested to me that I move "lib" into "web." I really don't know what's going on, 'cause, even though I no longer have any errors after moving "lib" to "web," I now have a different issue where my variables aren't updating properly :(

Comment: `lib` into `web` is definitively wrong but it's hard to tell what's the actual problem because your question does't provide enough information. Importing from a relative path is fine but this is not how to use the lib folder.

Comment: is there any other info I can provide that would help? I cloned down a tutorial and have only been modifying files in one folder. The folder root is called "s1_basics," under which I have a "lib," "packages," and "web" folder. Under "lib," I have "badge_controller.dart" and "pirate_module.dart". Under "packages," I have a ton of dart/angular dependencies, and finally, under "web," I have another "packages" folder, and "index.html," "main.dart, " and "piratebadge.css."

Comment: I'm not using the Dart editor, but instead regular Eclipse with the Dart plugin, but none of my files are giving me errors so I feel like everything's okay in that regard...just can't figure out why I'm getting an error upon launching "index.html." The error is: "An error occurred loading file: http://localhost:8081/lib/pirate_module.dart" and when I click on the link, it says "Could not find asset web/lib/pirate_module.dart in package s1_basics." Note the "web/lib" portion of that....why's it looking there? Is there anything I can copy/paste to help you help me?

Comment: Your last two comments contains some information I can works with. I don't know about Eclipse with the Dart plugin though. It doesn't look like the error is caused a bug in the source but rather by some execution problem. Can you try with the unmodified tutorial example and post if you get the same error?

Comment: Can you also please add a link to the tutorial source you are working with?

Comment: I actually figured it out by comparing my code against the ng-darrrt-codelab GitHub repo. For some reason, the relative paths weren't working. When I changed the import statement to "import 'package:s1_basics/pirate_module.dart'" it works. I must have been too tired last night and not thinking clearly. Thank you for your help!